# Can I have something like the Glyphicons buttons icons using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, icons

I am pretty new in **Jquery** development and I need to do the following thing. I have to add 3 **icons buttons**, something like the **BootStrap Glyphicons** button, these: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

In the specific case I need 2 Jquery button like the **glyphicon glyphicon-ok** **glyphicon glyphicon-remove** and also I need to create a custom icon button (using a custom icon).

Can I do something like this using **JQuery**?

Tnx

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do this in jQuery given that glyphicons is a font which is intended to be used in CSS...?

Comment: I suppose you want to create your buttons dynamically using jQuery? If so create them and add the right classes to it. More info about buttons and icons in Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples

Comment: I can't use BootStrap. I want to know if in JQuery there are some buttons that look like the BootStrap Glyphicons

Comment: You can download Glyphicons and use them without Bootstrap at [glyphicons.com](http://glyphicons.com). Then create a button using HTML and throw in `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>` as the text for the button. Using jQuery, you can generate html using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).